# Many to many relationship in erd

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I am creating database for entertainment application. In this movies,video songs,mp3 songs like entities are included. In this movie & actors,actresses,music directors,male singers, female singers have many to many relationships. i.e. an actor works in zero or many movies & a movie includes one or many actors. so my question is how to make these tables.

Comment: I added "database-design" tag, since I assume that is the base meaning of the question. Anyway, are you talking about how to model it in the database, or how the ER diagramm should look like?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

Actor Table:

- ActorID
- Actor Name

Film Table:

- FilmID
- FilmName

The Connection Table ActorFilm

- ActorID
- FilmID

Answer (score 0):

Your `actor` table would look like:

```
[ actorID Name Age....]
```

Your `movies` table could look like

```
[ movieID Name release_date....]
```

where `actorID` and `movieID` are primary keys. Now the many-to-many relationship between them can be represented as **another table** say `starring` as:

```
[ movieID actorID ]
```

a row in this table implies that the movie with the given ID has the actor with actorID in that row as a star.